# Adding TypeKit code (or any code) into the Head of a Magento 2 site

Tags: magento, head, magento2

All I want to do is to add a custom font from TypeKit into my Magento 2 website.

Previously I just used to find /app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/page/head.phtml and edit that. Simple.

With Magento 2 it seems to be hugely complicated. [I keep finding articles like this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_css_layout_woes). Do I really need to create an entire Module just to add 2 lines of basic HTML to the head of a document?

Surely there must be an easier way?

[I found this similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86243/add-custom-js-in-head-in-magento2), but I dont get the answer. Where do I create a layout file in my theme? Or is it suggesting I create a whole seperate Module again?

[I also found this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75106/include-javascript-from-module-in-magento-2), and it looks insane. Am I right in thinking that they are editing 3 seperate files, jsut to add a JS file into head?

Surely this cant be right? Isn't there a `head.phtml` file I can just edit?

Can someone break this down for me, assume I am an idiot, and explain how I can easily just add 2 lines of TypeKit code to the Head. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your magento admin area: Navigate to "Stores" menu item, under the heading "Settings", click "Configuration", once in "Configuration", click "Design".
Under the "HTML Head" section you will see a box saying "Miscellaneous Scripts" anything you add here will be added to the head section of the website.

Comment: this is the method i ended up using, so im marking you as correct

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about adding it into the phtml file just yet, however here is how I have added in custom fonts to my theme.

In:
`app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Using (example):

```
<block type="core/text" name="example_font">
    <action method="setText">
        <text>
            <![CDATA[<script src="https://blahblahblah.js"></script><script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>]]>
        </text>
    </action>
</block>
```

Then set it as base font / whatever you want in:
`app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/web/css/source/_variables.less`

Hope that helps even if just a bit!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, it looks like the "HTML Head" referred to here has been moved in the Magento 2 admin. It's now at:

**Admin > Content > Configuration > [Click "Edit" on your Theme Name] > Other Settings > HTML Head**

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the idea of using layout xml as per knarfeolhcs answer, the layout xml suggested isn't correct as type="core/text" doesn't exist in Magento 2. Here is the layout xml I used to add typekit `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.js" src_type="url" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="typekit">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>]]></argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```